# How to create a permalink structure with custom taxonomies and custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks

My custom taxonomy and custom post type are the followings -

```
// Creating a house Custom Post Type
function house_custom_post_type() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                => __( 'house' ),
        'singular_name'       => __( 'house'),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'house'),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent house'),
        'all_items'           => __( 'All house'),
        'view_item'           => __( 'View house'),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New house'),
        'add_new'             => __( 'Add New house'),
        'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit house'),
        'update_item'         => __( 'Update house'),
        'search_items'        => __( 'Search house'),
        'not_found'           => __( 'Not Found'),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash')
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'               => __( 'house'),
        'description'         => __( 'Best house'),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'revisions', 'custom-fields'),
        'public'              => true,
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'yarpp_support'       => true,
        'taxonomies'          => array( 'post_tag' ),
        'rewrite'             => array( 'slug' => '%house_type%', 'with_front' => false ), 
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'page'
    );
    register_post_type( 'house', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'house_custom_post_type', 0 );

//create a custom taxonomy name it "house_type" for your posts
function house_create_custom_taxonomy() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'house_type', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'house_type', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search house_type' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All house_type' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent house_type' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent house_type: ' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit house_type' ), 
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update house_type' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New house_type' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New house_type Name' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'house_type' ),
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'house_type', array( 'house' ), array(
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'house' ),
    ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'house_create_custom_taxonomy', 0 );

function add_my_post_types_to_query( $query ) {
    if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'house' ) );
    }
    return $query;
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_my_post_types_to_query' );

function mmp_rewrite_rules( $rules ) {
    $newRules = array();
    $newRules['basename/(.+)/?$']                = 'index.php?house_type=$matches[1]'; 
    $newRules['basename/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/?$'] = 'index.php?house=$matches[4]'; // my custom structure will always have the post name as the 5th uri segment
    return array_merge( $newRules, $rules );
}
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array', 'mmp_rewrite_rules' );

function filter_post_type_link( $link, $post ) {
    if ( $post->post_type != 'house') {
        return $link;
    }

    if ( $cats = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'house_type' ) ) {
        $link = str_replace( '%house_type%', get_taxonomy_parents( array_pop( $cats )->term_id, 'house_type', false, '/', true ), $link ); // see custom function defined below
    }
    return $link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'filter_post_type_link', 10, 2 );

function get_taxonomy_parents( $id, $taxonomy, $link = false, $separator = '/', $nicename = false, $visited = array() ) {
    $chain = '';
    $parent = &get_term( $id, $taxonomy );

    if ( is_wp_error( $parent ) ) {
        return $parent;
    }

    if ( $nicename ) {
        $name = $parent->slug;
    } else {
        $name = $parent->name;
    }

    if ( $parent->parent && ( $parent->parent != $parent->term_id ) && ! in_array( $parent->parent, $visited ) ) {
        $visited[] = $parent->parent;
        $chain .= get_taxonomy_parents( $parent->parent, $taxonomy, $link, $separator, $nicename, $visited );
    }

    if ( $link ) {

    } else {
        $chain .= $name . $separator;
    }
    return $chain;
}
```

I am using this custom function in my localhost all are working good but I have faced two errors in this my permalink structure post type is:

1) `http://localhost/project/house/bunglow/5bhk//my-houses/`

But near 5BHK create two separators `5bhk//my-houses/` I want to remove one separator, I want only one like this: `http://localhost/project/house/bunglow/5bhk/my-houses/` in `parent-tax/child-tax/` format.

2) And also open this link they give

> Oops! That page can’t be found

This link show this error display *page not found*. What the problem in my following function. Please help me its urgent.

Comment: @Jeff i read your ans and also use this in my function  but i m facing two problem please help me if u r freeeeee

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the extra slash is coming from the str_replace action because normally there's no need to manually add slashes when retrieving TAX urls.

Since you now end up with 1 unwanted slash, I would recommend testing situations with/without the slash. Starting with removing the one in the function definition. Make it empty, see what happens.

That is the first step to look into, in my opinion. I think this post might help you a bit as well: https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress